# custom text passed to ACTION_CALL activity

Tags: android

On Android 2.1+ I am calling a number that is not in the contacts database using the activity started by startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ptn)))  Since the number is not in the contacts database there is no name associated with the call.  I want to display a name with the called number so the user can verify the number the application is calling.

I tried using a LabeledIntent, but couldn't get it to work with ACTION_CALL.  Is there a way to make a call using the ACTION_CALL intent or through some other means where I can pass a name that will be displayed during the call?

Answer (score 0):

There are no Extras for this intent. So there's no way to specify a name.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`Intent.ACTION_CALL` does not support passing a name that will be displayed during the call.